# how to execute each line separately bash

Tags: bash

For example I have

```
3/4  swimming
2/5  running
```

But when I put them in a variabele like $number and $word and then do echo

```
number=$(cat $1 | cut -d ' ' -f1)
word=$(cat $1 | cut -d ' ' -f2)
echo $number $word
```

I get

```
3/4 2/5 swimming running
```

And because of this I will not be able to do calculations
and to get an output like this l

```
swimmi
run
```

Because 3/4 of swimming = swimmi

2/5 of running = run

Comment: You want to relace space by `*` then compute the line ?

Comment: Please make a [mre]. It's not clear how you're setting `$number1` and `$number2` and how you're using `echo`. It sounds like you're doing something wrong of course, but it's not clear what. Also, Bash only does integer arithmetic, so if you're already using `bc` or something, it'd help to show us, just for context. For more tips, check out [ask].

Comment: try `typeset -p number1 number2` to see what's actually stored in the 2 variables; also compare your current output - `echo $number1 $number2` - with the output when (properly) wrapping the variable references in double quotes - `echo "$number1" "$number2"`, or in this case add a delimiter to see where the values start and stop, eg: `echo ":$number1:" ":$number2:"`

Comment: The shell doesn't have floating point arithmetic

Comment: Does Gilles Quenot's answer help? If not please describe why not.

Comment: With your last change, you have completely changed the question, which makes the already given answer useless.

Comment: yes but they were not an answer to my question so I tried to make it clearer.

Comment: `while IFS=' /' read -r a b c; do echo $a $b $c; done < file` and this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74687920/how-do-you-split-a-word-in-the-given-fraction#comment131823799_74687920) might help.

Comment: If it's a correct answer to the question you _actually asked_, then it doesn't matter if it's not an answer to the question you wanted to ask; it's still a correct answer. Once there's a correct answer, start a new/different question if you asked something other than what you meant to.

Comment: That said, it sounds like you want something like `while IFS=$' \t/' read -r a b word; do ...` to put the `3` in `$a`, the `4` in `$b` and the word `swimming` in `$word`. As you've noticed, `cat file | cut ...` processes the whole file at once instead of giving you a line at a time. (Also, it's seriously inefficient compared to `cut ... <file`)

Comment: Try `while read -r number word; do printf '%s\n' "${word:0:${#word}*$number}"; done <"$1"`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ { echo "scale=2"; sed -E 's/[a-z]+//g' file; } | bc 
.75
.40
```

Comment: The spaces don't need to be changed by *